# openSUSE Leap not allowing to connect http on IP & hostname

Tags: http, port, firewall, opensuse

I have installed openSUSE 15.5 Leap as a virtual machine in Hyper-V and then installed jBoss 7.4 eap. I have disabled Firewall from yast. And deployed my webapplication in the jboss.
I am able to access my webapplication url with 'localhost' like
http://localhost:8080/MyApp

But I am not able to access this same app when I use my opensuse ip, 127.0.0.1,  like

http://172.20.9.180:8080/MyApp
http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp
http://opensuseleap155:8080/MyApp

All the above 3 urls are not launching my webapp instead throwing error Unable to Connect. I am not testing this outside the VM. This is happening even inside my openSuse guest OS even though I stopped FireWall from yast. Any help to find the root cause ?

Regards,
Manohar